# Fix pandas wrongly interpretting timestamps hh:mm:ss into yyyy-dd-mmThh:mm:ss

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I need to import a .xlsx sheet into pandas which has a column for the processing time of an associated activity. All entries in this column look somewhat like this:

```
01:20:34
12:22:30
25:01:02
155:20:56
```

Which says how much hours, minutes and seconds were needed. When I use `pd.read_excel` pandas correctly interprets each of the timestamps with less than 24 hours, and reads them as above in the first two cases. The timestamps with more than 24h (last two) on the other hand are converted into a datetime object, which in turn looks like this: `1900-01-02T14:58:03` instead of `62:58:03`.

Is there a simple solution?

Comment: Try reading it as a string by specifying the column dtype ?

Comment: @Chris Thank you, but for some reason it still converts it into the year, but now as a string instead of a datetime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that part of the problem is not in **Python/Pandas**, but in **Excel**. Date '1900-01-01' is the base date used by Excel represented by number '1'. You can check that if you write '0' in a cell and then formate that cell to date, you get '1900-01-00' and '1' you get '1900-01-01'.

So, try to export your Excel file to a CSV file before importing to pandas and then import this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('sample_data.csv')
```

In this case, you can get this DataFrame with the column Duration as a string (I added a column id for reference).

```
    duration   id
0   01:20:34    1
1   12:22:30    2
2   25:01:02    3
3  155:20:56    4
```

Then for your purpose, I suggest you Do not try to convert those values to `datetime` type, but a `timedelta`. A strategy will be to split the strings by colons and then build an instance of timedelta using those three fields: hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
import datetime as dt
def converter1(x):
    vals = x.split(':')
    vals = [int(val) for val in vals ]
    out = dt.timedelta(hours=vals[0], minutes=vals[1], seconds=vals[2])
    return out
df1['deltat'] = df1['duration'].apply(converter1)
```

```
    duration   id          deltat
0   01:20:34    1 0 days 01:20:34
1   12:22:30    2 0 days 12:22:30
2   25:01:02    3 1 days 01:01:02
3  155:20:56    4 6 days 11:20:56
```

If you need to convert those values to a number of decimals hours or other new fields use the `total_seconds()` method from `timedelta`:

```
df1['deltat_hr'] = df1['deltat'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds()/3600)
```

```
    duration   id          deltat   deltat_hr
0   01:20:34    1 0 days 01:20:34    1.342778
1   12:22:30    2 0 days 12:22:30   12.375000
2   25:01:02    3 1 days 01:01:02   25.017222
3  155:20:56    4 6 days 11:20:56  155.348889
```